# stuck in a problem in making a program to number of currency notes

Tags: python

I have an assignment to count currency notes of 1000,500,100,50,20 and 10,i tried many thing for loop and if condition but could not get the correct output.please guide me me the correct code and explanation.i want the output like 
input=Enter amount:1070
output=There are '1' 1000 note,'0' 500 note,'0' 100 notes,'1' 50 note,'1' 20 note,'0' 10 note in given amount.
simply output should be 1 note of 1000,1 note of 50,1 note of 20.

```
    while True:
                while True:
                            try:
                                amount = int(input('\nEnter First number:'))
                            except ValueError:
                                print("\nPlease enter only number")
                            else:
                                break
                if (amount>=1000):
                    n_1000=amount/1000
                if (amount>=500):
                    n_500=amount/500
                if (amount>=100):
                    n_100=amount/100
                if (amount>=50):
                    n_50=amount/50
                if (amount>=20):
                    n_20=amount/20
                if (amount>=10):
                    n_10=amount/10
                print("\nThere are {0} 1000 notes,{1} 500 notes,{2} 100 
               notes,{3} 50 notes,{4} 20 notes,{5} 10 notes in given 
               amount.".format(n_1000,n_500,n_100,n_50,n_20,n_10))
                while True:
                            Repeat=input("\nDo you want to repeat?\n\nYes or No:")
                            Repeat=Repeat.lower()
                            if Repeat not in ["yes","y","no","n"]:
                                print("\nPlease select correct option")
                            else:
                                break


                if Repeat in ["yes","y"]:
                    continue
                else:
                    if Repeat in ["no","n"]:
                        print("\n-----Thank you for using-----")
                        input()
                        break
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you be more specific about how your program is failing? Please read [ask] and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577)

Comment: Please explain in more detail how the current output of the code is different from what you want.

Comment: with this code the output is '1.70' 1000 notes and i want '1' 1000 note,'1' 50 note,'1' 20 note

Comment: Use [`divmod()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) instead of division to get both the whole number of a certain note and the amount that remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code is this,no need for condition or loop.

```
    while True:
                while True:
                            try:
                                amount = int(input('\nEnter First number:'))
                            except ValueError:
                                print("\nPlease enter only number")
                            else:
                                break
                n_1000=amount//1000
                amount=amount-(n_1000*1000)
                n_500=amount//500
                amount=amount-(n_500*500)
                n_100=amount//100
                amount=amount-(n_100*100)
                n_50=amount//50
                amount=amount-(n_50*50)
                n_20=amount//20
                amount=amount-(n_20*20)
                n_10=amount//10
                amount=amount-(n_10*10)
                l_amount=amount
                print("\nThere are {0} 1000 notes,{1} 500 notes,{2} 100 notes,{3} 50 notes,{4} 20 notes,{5} 10 notes and {6} is left in given amount.".format(n_1000,n_500,n_100,n_50,n_20,n_10,l_amount))
                while True:
                            Repeat=input("\nDo you want to repeat?\n\nYes or No:")
                            Repeat=Repeat.lower()
                            if Repeat not in ["yes","y","no","n"]:
                                print("\nPlease select correct option")
                            else:
                                break


                if Repeat in ["yes","y"]:
                    continue
                else:
                    if Repeat in ["no","n"]:
                        print("\n-----Thank you for using-----")
                        input()
                        break

        if Repeat in ["yes","y"]:
            continue
        else:
            if Repeat in ["no","n"]:
                print("\n-----Thank you for using-----")
                input()
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ran your code, in python division of ints can produce a float, so you need to use the `//` operator (which returns an int). You also might want to change the amount, so to not return the same change from every note, that is for 1000, your current code will return "there are 1 1000 note, 2 500 notes" etc, you can change every if statement to

```
if (amount >= 1000):
    n_1000 = amount // 1000
    amount %= 1000
```

And it would be alot easier if you will keep a list of notes, and iterate through it

Comment: Maybe use `amount -= n_1000`. Or  [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) is handy for this operation. You might want to show conditionals for the  other notes to get your point across.

Comment: i did what you said but still could not get the correct answer,i want the same code as i have but the right code

Comment: @waseem12312 Sorry, had a typo, i've edited the code, I meant the modulo operator (%), this version now works

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a better solution to your task:

```
END_COMMAND = 'quit'

def func():
    while True:
        while True:
            amount = input('Enter an integer amount (or type "{}"):'.format(END_COMMAND))\
                .lower().strip()
            if amount == END_COMMAND:
                print('Received "{}" instruction'.format(END_COMMAND))
                return

            try:
                amount = int(amount)
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('Error: "{}" is not a valid integer'.format(amount))

        print('Composition for amount "{:,d}":'.format(amount))
        for denomination in [1000, 500, 100, 50, 20, 10, 1]:
            n, amount = divmod(amount, denomination)

            if n > 0:
                print('   {:6,d} of denomination {:6,d}'.format(n, denomination))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    func()
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is the simplest solution to your question

```
n = int(input("Enter an amount"))
    twothousands=int((n/2000))
    fivehundred=int((n%2000) / 500)
    hundreds=int((n %500)/100)
    fifties =int((n%100)/50)
    tens=int((n%500)%50/10)
    ones=int(((n%500)%50)%10)
    print("2000:{} 500:{} 100:{} 50:{} 10:{} 1:{}".format(twothousands,fivehundred,hundreds,fifties,tens,ones))
```

#python

Comment: Would you mind adding some explanation?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).